# Twitterizer returning 401 on TwitterStatus.Update

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

Good looking library, but it's misbehaving for me..

I've created a twitter app, with read/write permissions, and that all seems good.

I was working with full lifecycle oauth management, but am now using the "Access token secret" and "Access token: generated within twitter on the app admin page.

My code is here

https://gist.github.com/2892292

```
var tokens = new OAuthTokens
                         {
                             AccessToken = [MyAccess],
                             AccessTokenSecret = [MySecret],
                             ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey,
                             ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret
                         };


        var verify = TwitterAccount.VerifyCredentials(tokens);
```

Its dead simple code, but is returning a 'Twitterizer.RequestResult.Unauthorized' for the result object..

Answer (score 0):

Through the magic of being a goof. I had my secret / key backwards... jeez.

If having issues, I highly recomend using the twitter oauth tool to generate an example header, and then run twitterizer through fiddler or some such to compare the headers.

sigh.